# Why does .attr() work on $(this) but not on parameter from each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I am using cheerio (i.e jQuery server side) on node.js to parse a web page.
When trying to get the `href` attribute of an element I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'attr'

My code is:

```
$('#commandes_pagination li a').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.attr('href'));
});
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<ul class="liste04" id="commandes_pagination">
    <li>        
        <a shape="rect" title="" href="/refonte/account/ajax/orderlist/1" class="page_num page_active" id="commandes_page-1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a shape="rect" title="" href="/refonte/account/ajax/orderlist/2" class="page_num" id="commandes_page-2">2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can get it working by using `$(this).attr("href")` instead of `element.attr("href")` but I can't figure out why. Any explanation much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `element` variable passed in to the `each()` handler is a native JS DOM element which does not have the `attr()` method. You need to convert it to a jQuery object in order to use `attr()` on it:

```
$('#commandes_pagination li a').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr('href'));
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `console.log(element.href);` if you want to keep the native object.

Comment: +1 but should be said than `element.href` returns the absolute path, if it does matter

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first guess would be that element is not a jquery object. I went ahead and checked it using:

```
$('#commandes_pagination li a').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element instanceof jQuery);
});
```

And I found my guess was right.
If you specifically want to use element then you can use:

```
$('#commandes_pagination li a').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr("href"));
});
```

You will see it works. You could have achieved the same result by logging the element variable. You would have seen its not a jquery object.